# How does orbital eccentricity affect positions of Lagrange points $L_4$ and $L_5$?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbit, lagrangian-points, gravity-fields

It is often said that the $L_4$ and $L_5$ points are "60 degrees ahead and behind" a planet like Jupiter. Clearly this is true only in the case of circular orbits. In more elliptical orbits, I assume the rule of thumb would be that the $L_4$ and $L_5$ are at the points on the orbit that are equidistant from the planet and barycenter. Would that be a safe assumption?

Answer (score 7):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_point):

> In the more general case of elliptical orbits, there are no longer
>   stationary points in the same sense: it becomes more of a Lagrangian
>   “area”. The Lagrangian points constructed at each point in time, as in
>   the circular case, form stationary elliptical orbits which are similar
>   to the orbits of the massive bodies.

A more complete answer is given in [this paper](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1992AN....313..315T). It concludes that yes, L4 and L5 are at the points on the orbit that are equidistant from the planet and barycenter.

Comment: Interestingly, this paragraph is no longer present in the Wikipedia article on "Lagrange point" as of this date.